# Bold small caps in Cyrillic with erewhon

Tags: fonts, bold, small-caps, cyrillic

The README file of `erewhon` package claims that

> Erewhon adds small caps in all styles

However, with

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{erewhon}
\begin{document}
    \scshape Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум \bfseries Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

so obviously small caps don't work in bold Cyrillic.

Is there a way to get them?

Comment: Apparently, the font developers didn't provide boldface small caps for Cyrillic.

Comment: I am all for font completeness, but as a side notice: as far as I know, small caps (and even more so: in more exotic weights) are less used in traditional Cyrillic typography.

Comment: As of 2021-01-16, `erewhon` has been updated, but there is still a glitch with font maps. `:-(`

Comment: @egreg, oddly enough, the small caps in Cyrillic now work for the bold weight (both upright and italic), but not for regular. I wrote to the package developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2021-01-20

Version 1.113 of the erewhon font package has fixed the issue.

#### Original answer

The `T2A-erewhon-TLF.fd` file that defines the fonts for Cyrillic erewhon has

```
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{b}{scsl}{
      <-> \erewhon@@scale Erewhon-BoldSlanted-tlf-sc-t2a
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{b}{sc}{
      <-> \erewhon@@scale Erewhon-Bold-tlf-sc-t2a
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{b}{scit}{
      <-> ssub * erewhon-TLF/b/scsl
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{m}{scsl}{
      <-> \erewhon@@scale Erewhon-RegularSlanted-tlf-sc-t2a
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{m}{sc}{
      <-> \erewhon@@scale Erewhon-Regular-tlf-sc-t2a
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{m}{scit}{
      <-> ssub * erewhon-TLF/m/scsl
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{bx}{scsl}{
      <-> ssub * erewhon-TLF/b/scsl
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{bx}{sc}{
      <-> ssub * erewhon-TLF/b/sc
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T2A}{erewhon-TLF}{bx}{scit}{
      <-> ssub * erewhon-TLF/b/scit
}{}
```

(only the entries related to small caps are shown).

So the font chosen when `\scshape\bfseries` is in force should be `Erewhon-Bold-tlf-sc-t2a` and this is indeed what's reported if I request `\fontname\font`, which prints the current external font name.

On the other hand, running `pdflatex nfssfont` and issuing `Erewhon-Bold-tlf-sc-t2a` at the prompt produces

[image]

(only the part relevant to Cyrillic is shown). Similar result is obtained with `Erewhon-BoldSlanted-tlf-sc-t2a`.

Only the regular and slanted (which is also used if italic is asked for) have proper smallcaps glyphs.

Unfortunately, also the OpenType version has the same problem, so it seems you're out of luck unless the font developer releases a fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wrote to the developer.

Answer (score 1):

With the OpenType version of the fonts, you can fake it ’till they make it.  This MWE requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and TeX Live 2020.

```
\documentclass[russian]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures[Erewhon]{
  Scale = 1.0,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = *-Regular,
                   SmallCapsFeatures = { Letters= SmallCaps,
                                         FakeBold = 1.75}
                 },
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  SlantedFont = *-RegularSlanted,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  BoldItalicFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = *-RegularSlanted,
                         SmallCapsFeatures = { Letters= SmallCaps,
                                               FakeBold = 1.75}
                       },
  BoldSlantedFont = *-BoldSlanted,
  BoldSlantedFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = *-RegularSlanted,
                          SmallCapsFeatures = { Letters= SmallCaps,
                                                FakeBold = 1.75}
                        },
  Extension = .otf }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Erewhon}
\setmathfont{Erewhon Math}

\begin{document}
  \noindent Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум} \\
  \textsc{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум}} \\
  \itshape Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум} \\
  \itshape\textsc{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум}} \\
  \slshape Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум} \\
  \slshape\textsc{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Лорем Ипсум}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Erewhon sample]

Comment: Thanks! The developer has already promised me to post an update to CTAN within few days.